# Make object by its name

Tags: c++, class, object, creation

is it possible to return exemplar of object using passed type name (string) in c++?
I have some base abstract class `Base` and a few derivates. Example code:

```
class Base
{
   /* ... */
};

class Der1 : public Base
{
   /* ... */
};

class Der2 : public Base
{
   /* ... */
};
```

And I need function like:

```
Base *objectByType(const std::string &name);
```

Number of derivates classes are changeable and I don't want to make something like switching of `name` and returning by hands new object type. Is it possible in c++ to do that automatically anyway?

p.s. usage should looks like:

```
dynamic_cast<Der1>(objectByType("Der1"));
```

---

I need pure c++ code (crossplatform). Using boost is permissible.

Comment: This sounds a OS specific question. Which OS are we taling about?

Comment: @sad_man, look at update, please. I need crossplatform version.

Comment: How can "the number of derivatives" be changable? Are you willing to call the derivatives from an external library that is compiled after your application?

Comment: @sad_man, I mean that I will add derivates more and more and I don't want to edit that function when new class is added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a nice trick which allows you to write a [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) without a sequence of `if...else if...`.

(note that, AFAIK, it is indeed not possible to do what you want in C++ as this code is generated in the compile time. A "Factory Method" [Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_%28computer_science%29) exists for this purpose)

First, you define a `global repository` for your derived classes. It can be in the form `std::map<std::string, Base*>`, i.e. maps a name of the derived class to `an instance` of that class.

For each derived class you define a `default constructor` which adds an object of that class to the repository under class's name. You also define a static instance of the class:

```
// file: der1.h
#include "repository.h"

class Der1: public Base {
public:
  Der1() { repository[std::string("Der1")] = this; }
};

// file: der1.cpp
static Der1 der1Initializer;
```

Constructors of static variables are run even before `main()`, so when your `main` starts you already have the repository initialized with instances of all derived classes.

Your factory method (e.g. `Base::getObject(const std::string&)`) needs to search the repository map for the class name. It then uses the `clone()` method of the object it finds to get a new object of the same type. You of course need to implement `clone` for each subclass.

The advantage of this approach is that when you are adding a new derived class your additions are restricted only to the file(s) implementing the new class. The repository and the factory code will not change. You will still need to recompile your program, of course.

Comment: Default constructor is a BAD way to do this.  Just create an ordinary global variable, like an `int`, that is initialized with a call to the factory's setup function.  e.g. `static int g_factoryDer1Registration = Der1Factory::Register();`  Or create an instance of a nested helper class.  But don't create an instance of the type the factory is generating, in order to register the factory, that violates the single responsibility principle in every possible way.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: thanks for pointing this out. Indeed, using a dedicated `Der1Factory::Register()` method looks better.

Comment: Good idea, and without switch/if statements.

Comment: How about the order of initialization of static variables? Won't this be a problem if the variable der1Initialzer/g_factoryDer1Registration is initialized before the repository map?

Comment: @rstevens: I suppose you can enforce some order, e.g. if you define a `Repository` (or `Factory`) class with a `static Repository::Register()` method that uses a static local `std::map`

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to do this in C++.

One options is to write a factory and switch on the name passed in, but I see you don't want to do that. C++ doesn't provide any real runtime reflection support beyond dynamic_cast, so this type of problem is tough to solve.

Comment: you can write a factory without `switch` - see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible! Check this very funny class called [`Activator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
You can create everything by `Type` and `string` and can even give a List of parameters, so the method will call the appropriate constructor with the best set of arguments.

Comment: I do not believe the question is asked for .Net.

Comment: Is it crossplatform and available for c++? I see it's based on .Net or smth like that.

Comment: Wrong language, wrong framework (unless the OP failed to mention that he uses C++/CLI instead of C++, which is unlikely).

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstood, the `typeid` keyword should be a part of what you are looking for.

Comment: No. `typeid` provides a mapping from types to type-describing objects (including the type name as a string), but the inverse mapping is not available in C++.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. You have to write the `objectByType` function yourself:

```
Base* objectByType(const std::string& name) {
  if (name == "Der1")
    return new Der1;
  else if (name == "Der2")
    return new Der2;
  // other possible tests
  throw std::invalid_argument("Unknown type name " + name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't support [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_science%29).

In my opinion this is the single point where Java beats C++.
(ope not to get too many down votes for this...)

You could achieve something like that by using a custom preprocessor, similar to how MOC does for Qt.